# draw flighroute on mercator map how to calculate polyline points with a given longitude

Tags: dictionary, latitude-longitude, mercator

i would like to draw a polyline on a Mercator map between two cities. e.g Startpoints:

```
 Location berlin = new Location(52.517, 13.40);
 Location tokio = new Location(35.70,139.767);
```

it should look like a flight route.

so my plan was to go through all longitude values between the two cities and calculate corresponding latitude values:

```
LocationCollection locationCollection = new LocationCollection();

Location next = new Location(berlin.Latitude,berlin.Longitude); //startpunkt
for (double x = berlin.Longitude+1; x < tokio.Longitude; x++) {
  locationCollection.Add(next);
  next = new Location(???, x);
}
```

the question is how can i calculate the latitude for each longitude value for the polyline?
Thanks!

Comment: That's a mathematical question more than anything. y-y1 = k(x-x1) will is a starting point for you. http://www.skwirk.com.au/p-c_s-12_u-83_t-151_c-479/two-point-formula/nsw/two-point-formula/coordinate-geometry/linear-equations

Comment: @HampusBrynolf Cartesian straight line interpolation isn't going to work for angular geographical coordinates.

Comment: true already tried to convert all points on the Cartesian straight line to polar coordinates but the result was just a straight line too. (as far as I can remember)

Comment: http://www.kowoma.de/gps/geo/grosskreise2d.gif I would like to draw the yellow line on the map:

Answer (score 0):

From [this link](http://williams.best.vwh.net/avform.htm#Int):

Here's an implementation in C.

```
#define PI 3.14159265358979323846
double degrees_radians(double d) { return d * PI / 180.0; }
double radians_degrees(double r) { return r * 180.0 / PI; }

double latitude(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2, double lon)
{
    return atan((sin(lat1)*cos(lat2)*sin(lon-lon2)-sin(lat2)*cos(lat1)*sin(lon-lon1))/(cos(lat1)*cos(lat2)*sin(lon1-lon2)));
}

int main()
{
    // start and end in degrees
    double lat1_d = 52.517;
    double lon1_d = 13.40;
    double lat2_d = 35.70;
    double lon2_d = 139.767;

    // start and end in radians
    double lat1_r = degrees_radians(lat1_d);
    double lon1_r = degrees_radians(lon1_d);
    double lat2_r = degrees_radians(lat2_d);
    double lon2_r = degrees_radians(lon2_d);

    // interpolate latitide at every degree of longitude between 1 and 2
    for (double lon = ceil(lon1_d); lon < lon2_d; lon += 1.0)
    {
        double lat_r = latitude(lat1_r, lon1_r, lat2_r, lon2_r, degrees_radians(lon));
        double lat_d = radians_degrees(lat_r);
        printf("%.3f , %.3f\n", lat_d, lon);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The maximum latitude reached on the great circle between Berlin and Tokyo is then shown to be 66.183° at longitude 68°.